# What is the meaning of this symbol $\ll_d$?

Tags: geometry, notation, computer-science, computational-geometry, integer-programming

I apologize for the simple question but I'm reading a paper "On the Convex Hull Of The Integer Points In A Disc" and I'm confused by some notation. They say
$$\# \textrm{ vertices of }P \ll_{\;d} (vol P)^{\frac{d-1}{d+1}}$$
And I'm unfamiliar with the meaning of $\ll_{\;d}$. Here, $P \subset R^d$ is a convex polytope with integral vertices and nonempty interior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the left side is bounded by a constant $C_{d} > 0$ times the right side, and the constant $C_{d}$ depends only on the number $d$ and nothing else.

Sometimes this is written instead with "big O" notation $x= O_{d}(y)$ (or, equivalently, $x\leq O_{d}(y)$).

**
Added later by request: A source for this notation is the wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations)

The link talks about the meaning of $\ll$ as the same thing as big O. This is also called "Vinogradov's notation". It's common practice to put subscripts if the implicit constant in the big O depends on some parameters.

It's probably good to caution that sometimes people interpret $\ll$ as "much much less than" which might make one think of "little o" notation. So maybe it's always good to read carefully. But the article in the question explicitly says Vinogradov's notation.

Here's another good article which talks about these issues:

[https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf)

Sections 2.1.5, 2.1.6, and 2.1.7 are relevant to everything I've said.

Comment: Can you share source(s) of your definition, please?

Comment: @zkutch I added it

Comment: Thanks for source, but there I see only $\ll$, not $O_{d}(y)$. Can you, please, point to from where you took this last one?

Comment: @zkutch The sources gives equivalence between $x\ll y$ and $x\leq O(y)$. As I say in the edit, adding a subscript for dependence on a parameter $d$ (either as $\ll_d$ or $O_d$) is a standard and well-used convention. You can google asymptotic notation and find many examples, such as: in https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf

Comment: Thanks again for pdf. I found on 12p dependence on parameters, but still I nowhere see $x \leq O_{d}(y)$. Also I do not see such on wiki. I had missed it somewhere?

Comment: @zkutch Again, the Wikipedia article explains $\ll$, and I'm saying that adding parameters is a standard convention (even though it's not not addressed by wikipedia). See page 16 of the pdf.

Comment: I am speaking exactly about "$x \leq O_{d}(y)$" - such indication is nowhere and more so on p16. It is not in wiki too. Can explain you explain it, or show source? Thanks.

Comment: OK perhaps you are asking about "$x \leq O(y)$" vs "$x= O(y)$" (or "$x\leq O_d(y)$" vs "$x=O_d(y)$")? These are viewed as synonymous, so they mean the same thing. It's a matter of personal preference. But the "big O" concept is talking about *upper bounds*, so that's probably why some people prefer $\leq$ to $=$.

Comment: In my answers on this site you can find how many I wrote about $O$, to be sure, that I know it's definition. Now I am working on one paper on some properties of $O$, so this why I am interesting in everything about. I didn't meet "$x \leq O(y)$" nor separate, nor as synonym, before your answer, so this is why I asked about it. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: @zkutch Ok I see. I think $=$ is more "official", but $\leq$ gets used a lot in proofs when writing more complicated statements or using multiple inequalities. For example both are used in this paper: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/keevash/papers/turan-survey.pdf. For example in Section 6. But I edited my answer to give preference to $=$ like in Wikipedia.

Comment: I see suggestion to move our conversation to chat and I am agree to it, but before your decision let me introduce my ideas here:  as $O(f)$ by definition is some set of functions, then I suggest sign "$=$" in big-$O$ notation understand as equality between sets, when we have $O(f)=O(g)$ type of equality so as "$\subset \land \supset$". Equality of type $f=O(g)$ is more ambiguous. I personally agree to  understand "$f \in O(g)$" and think, that introducing new "$f \leqslant O(g)$" only complicates situation. I want to express more, but came up to message limit, so am waiting for chat.

Comment: @zkutch I'll just say that $f\leq O(g)$ is not new and I did not introduce it. It is common notation used for many years, but perhaps more in discrete math and combinatorics vs number theoretic $f\ll g$. There is also established understanding of $O(f)=O(g)$, which is not the same was what you propose. See 2.2.2 of the pdf. For example $O(f)=O(g)$ is not a symmetric relation. This is one reason why I think $\leq$ *clarifies* the situation rather than complicates it. With $O(f)\leq O(g)$ there is much less ambiguity and risk of confusion.

Comment: But all in all it depends on whether one is thinking of sets of functions or using big O to ignore absolute constants in some calculations. We can do a chat if you wish, but I might not have much more to contribute